# Process more than 50K records in trigger

Tags: trigger, soql, governorlimits

One area where I'm having a tough time in the interview is soql.
Here are some questions which I'm not able to figure out.

1. How can we process more than 50K records in the trigger?
   One use case is on update of Account I want to update its related Contact and there are more than 50K contacts per account
2. How can we return more than 50K records in SOQL? I know there is limitation of 
   50K but what should I do if I want more records.

Comment: This question is not very specific. Without a use case, I think it's off topic.